# query for Select distinct rows and maximum of auto generated test id?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

[image]
this is my table `manufacture_data`.I need to get all data of `distinct manufacture_name` and maximum of `test_id` for each. that means i need to get row with test id 4 and 6.

can anyone help?

Comment: can you please more clear and send table structure

Comment: You are almost there. Use `group by` to complete your query.

Comment: sorry .. i just edited my question

Comment: i am entry level in sql

Comment: `select max(test_id) test_id , manufacture_name from manufacture_data group by manufacture_name`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT *  from manufacture_data    
ORDER BY Test_id DESC
) t
GROUP BY t.`manufacture_name`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT  Test_id  from manufacture_data 
WHERE Test_id IN ( SELECT MAX(Test_id) FROM manufacture_data GROUP BY manufacture_name)
```

[DEMO HERE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/591e6/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MANUFACTURE_NAME, MAX(TEST_ID) AS 'ID'
FROM TABLE T
GROUP BY MANUFACTURE_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select max(test_id) AS ID , manufacture_name from manufacture_data group by manufacture_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select manufacture_data.* from manufacture_data
join (select Manufacture_Name, max(Test_id) as maxId from manufacture_data group by Manufacture_Name) as tmp 
on manufacture_data.Test_id = tmp.maxId
```

Comment: My query retrieving records which Test_id is max. the sub select to select the max Test_id for each Manufacture_Name and the main select just retrieving record where Test_id in the sub select.